# How do I make this VBA-code function properly in my Excelfile?

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to make the current date in the file (Sheet 1, cell I3) update every 10 seconds, but after trying multiple things, it just won't work.

My plan was to make the time in the cell update every 10 seconds, instead of having to edit the file to update the time.
I am not familiar with VBA, could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
Sub Calculate_Range()

 Worksheets("Display").Range(I3).Calculate

 Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 10, Now), "Calculate_Range"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your code located in a regular module?

Comment: *every 10 seconds* As far as I know, there is no event in Excel VBA to execute a code every specific time. The only way would be creating a sub to keep executing and that would be terrible because it would block Excel. Not worth it. Why do you need the cell to be updated every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with this.

```
Dim TimeRQ As Date
Sub RQ()
With Sheet1.Range("I3")
.Value = Format(Time, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
End With
Call DeffTime
End Sub
Sub DeffTime()
TimeRQ = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime TimeRQ, "RQ"
End Sub
Sub Disable()
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=TimeRQ, Procedure:="RQ", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```